# SQL (mysql) sort table and get row with its position in the sorted table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

Basically I have this table:

Table
QID, UID, system, added(unix timestamp), errors

What Im trying to do is to select a row via UID, But before that sort the table by 'added' so its in timestamps DESC order and then get the single row with its position in the sorted table.

I currently have this which does rank the rows, but how would I get the single row from it:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank := @rank +1 AS rank, UID
FROM table
GROUP BY UID
ORDER BY added DESC
```

Comment: can you provide the example dataset with your expected result set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1 AS rank FROM table
WHERE added < (SELECT added FROM table WHERE UID=123)
```

Or maybe this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @rank := @rank+1 AS rank, UID
    FROM table
    GROUP BY UID
    ORDER BY added ASC
) tmp WHERE UID=123
```

Comment: The top one works fine after an initial entry check.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT @rank := @rank +1 AS rank, UID, added
      FROM (SELECT UID, added
            FROM t cross join
                   (SELECT @rank := 0) var
            GROUP BY UID
            ORDER BY added ASC
           ) t
     ) t
WHERE UID = 12346;
```

One problem is that `added` is indeterminate when there are multiple rows for a given `UID`.  I suspect that you want `MAX(added)` instead.

Comment: Ive got this data https://i.imgur.com/xEGS740.png and ive tried using this, but it always returns with rank 1. (with ASC or DESC)

Comment: @TristanCunningham . . . My bad.  I forgot that MySQL needs and extra level when using variables with `group by`.  Here is a little SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5a47/10.